# Nav Tabs stopped showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page I have been working on, which has some nav tabs on it, which has been working fine until yesterday. When I booted up this am the page no longer shows the tabs.  I have closed and reopened VS, I have rebooted my system as well as rebuilding the solution.  I've gone through all my code to make sure all tags are closed.  I've even gone as far as creating a whole new stand alone page with basic nav tab code and nothing, it doesn't show on the page at all. Any Ideas?

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Mango.WebForm2" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">TabA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TabB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TabC</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="TabA" class="tab-pane active">
            TAB A
            </div>

            <div id="TabB" class="tab-pane">
            TAB B
            </div>

            <div id="TabC" class="tab-pane">
            TAB C
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    $(this).tab('show')
                });

                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    e.relatedTarget // previous tab
                });
            });
        </script>

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I can see the tabs fine, check [my demo](http://www.bootply.com/LU1xt696KD).

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: And what version of jQuery?

Comment: Not what I'm seeing.   I just see the word     TabA    with no tabs whatsoever.

Comment: I'm using Chrome version 39.0.2171.99 m, but have also tested it on IE, Comodo all with same results. As I mentioned it has been working fine for days. Just started acting up this AM.  As for Jquery, I'm running  v1.10.2